# How do you interrogate someone?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-ground-zeroes

How do you grab an enemy, pull out your knife, and interrogate them (with and without a controller)? I've always been curious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can grab an enemy by pressing and holding the CQC button while near them.
After that, an overlay will appear with several options: "Interrogate", "Kill", and two times "Knock out", as well as how to perform each.

**Knocking an enemy out** can be done in two different ways:

- Press a direction<sup>**1**</sup> and at the same time quickly press the CQC button after releasing it. Snake will smash the enemy's skull to the ground, knocking them out instantly and also generating a lot of noise, which can attract nearby enemies.

  You can also do this without grabbing the enemy. Just move towards them and keep the direction<sup>**1**</sup> pressed and mash the CQC button to quickly knock them out.
- Mash the CQC button. Snake will choke the enemy unconscious, which will take some time, but is completely silent<sup>**2**</sup>.

**Killing** the enemy is done by pressing the "Contextual Action" button while still holding the CQC button.

**Interrogating** the enemy is done by pressing the Radio button while still holding the CQC button. While holding the CQC and the Radio buttons you'll see several options, such as "Spit it out" (ask for information) and "Call them" (attract a random nearby enemy), which you'll have to select by pressing a direction<sup>**1**</sup>. After pressing the desired direction, Snake will talk; do not let go of the Radio button while Snake or the enemy are talking or Snake will interrupt the interrogation, which may be useful if another enemy approaches and you need to move to some more secluded area.

---

<sup>**1**</sup>: Arrow keys on PC or left analog stick on consoles.
<sup>**2**</sup>: There is a possibility that choking an enemy on the PS3 is done just like in MGS 2, MGS 3 (both PS2) and MGS 4 (PS3); by applying more pressure to the CQC button. This is because the PS2 and PS3 controllers both feature pressure sensitive buttons, which every other console — including the PS4 — lack. This is purely speculative, as I don't own the PS3 version of MGS: GZ.

Comment: I know the question was about grabbing and interrogating only, but I decided to explain killing and knocking out as well, as they're all related to grabbing.

Answer (score 1):

Sneak up behind the enemy invisibly and quietly. Knock him out until he is unconscious. Wait until he wakes up or you can make him get back up then point your weapon right from behind him. Ask him questions and force him to talk. You can either tell him to call his teammates, force him to tell you the locations of your enemies or kill him.